# redirect page if load page is empty Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect

I'm using following code to load the div for every 5 sec.

**home.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
        $('#alert').load('alert.php').fadeIn("fast");
    }, 5000);

</script>
```

But want, if **alert.php** is empty I want redirect current page(home.php) to `www.example.com` .

How?

Comment: `$('#alert').load('alert.php', function() {
    if ($('#alert').html() == '') {
        window.location.href = 'home.php';
    }
}).fadeIn("fast");`

Comment: set redirect in alert.php for this check

Comment: @JasbirSinghSohanpal that would redirect the request, not the page the user is viewing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `promise` and `done` functions from jquery which will work once all content is **loaded** from `index.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
                $('#alert').load('alert.php').fadeIn("fast").promise().done(function(){
                    if($(this).html()=="") {
                        window.location.href = "home.php";
                    }
                });
            }, 5000);
  });
 </script>
```

see if it works for you

> For reference take a look at  [**promise()**](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) and [**done()**](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)